# Extending the scope of a DAO

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I have a typical DAO to fetch SQL objects from a table, but now I need to be able to query for objects placed in another physical database using foreign keys. Due to restrictions in my ORM I cannot create a query that joins over the two databases and hence I need to do this reduction step myself. To not introduce dependencies between DAOs I thought to myself that I should increase the level of abstraction and introduce a service on top of this DAO that does this for me. Is this the way to go or am I more confused than I think I am?

Comment: This seems fine to me, but be careful not raising the level of abstraction to a point where a completely artificial type of entity appears : http://ayende.com/blog/153699/ask-ayende-repository-for-abstracting-multiple-data-sources

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your "increased level of abstraction service" will be still "DAO" (and nothing more) I would just call it DAO and inject your base DAO service.

Semantically it will be completely correct.

Comment: Indeed it will. Thanks!